# Batch file to perform start, run, %TEMP% and delete all

Tags: batch-file

looking for a way to perform the following:

Start > Run > "%TEMP% > Delete everything (skipping any conflicts).

so Far I have

```
@echo off
start %TEMP%
DEL *.*
```

I suppose I could use CD to get to the folder, the thing I'm wondering is if there are any instances where it cannot delete an a dialog box comes up, I want to skip these.

Thanks for the help!
Liam

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`del` won't trigger any dialogs or message boxes. You have a few problems, though:

1. `start` will just open Explorer which would be useless. You need `cd` to change the working directory of your batch file (the `/D` is there so it also works when run from a different drive):

   ```
   cd /D %temp%
   ```
2. You may want to delete directories as well:

   ```
   for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
   ```
3. You need to skip the question for `del` and remove read-only files too:

   ```
   del /f /q *
   ```

so you arrive at:

```
@echo off
cd /D %temp%
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Works a charm, can now schedule it weekly with task scheduler!

Comment: One issue I am facing. "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." when trying for second time. Do we need to kill something?

Comment: Why would you need to loop thru all the directories in the batch when RD can do it by itself?  

@echo off
del %temp%  /f /s /q >nul
rd  %TEMP%  /S /Q>nul

Comment: @arana: Because `RD` will also remove the directory you specified along with anything beneath it. That may be fine in some cases, but typically I avoid this, as re-creating the directory could lead to issues (different ACLs, etc.).

Comment: This is great. I used to do nested loops, one /R to get all the files, and then a loop that POP to delete the directories once they were empty. However later I created this nested loop to write to each file "echo junk > file.* And then double back to delete the files and dirs.

Answer (score 11):

The following batch commands are used to delete all your temp, recent and prefetch files on your System.

Save the following code as "Clear.bat" on your local system

```
*********START CODE************

@ECHO OFF

del /s /f /q %userprofile%\Recent\*.*

del /s /f /q C:\Windows\Prefetch\*.*

del /s /f /q C:\Windows\Temp\*.*

del /s /f /q %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\*.*


/Below command to Show the folder after deleted files

Explorer %userprofile%\Recent

Explorer C:\Windows\Prefetch

Explorer C:\Windows\Temp

Explorer %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp


*********END CODE************
```

Comment: The prefetch seems very small. What's the reasoning? Is it a  log (spyware) that carries personal data?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove all the files in the `%TEMP%` folder you could just do this:

```
del %TEMP%\*.* /f /s /q
```

That will remove everything, any file with any extension (`*.*`) and do the same for all sub-folders (`/s`), without prompting you for anything (`/q`), it will just do it, including read only files (`/f`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It won't remove directories, though.

Comment: @Joey True, your answer is better :)

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
RD %TEMP%\. /S /Q

::pause
explorer %temp%
```

This batch can run from anywhere.
RD stands for Remove Directory but this can remove both folders and files which available to delete.

Answer (score 2):

cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local
 rmdir /S /Q Temp

del C:\Windows\Prefetch*.* /Q

del C:\Windows\Temp*.* /Q

del C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items*.* /Q
pause

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off    
del /s /f /q %windir%\temp\*.*    
rd /s /q %windir%\temp    
md %windir%\temp    
del /s /f /q %windir%\Prefetch\*.*    
rd /s /q %windir%\Prefetch    
md %windir%\Prefetch    
del /s /f /q %windir%\system32\dllcache\*.*    
rd /s /q %windir%\system32\dllcache    
md %windir%\system32\dllcache    
del /s /f /q "%SysteDrive%\Temp"\*.*    
rd /s /q "%SysteDrive%\Temp"    
md "%SysteDrive%\Temp"    
del /s /f /q %temp%\*.*    
rd /s /q %temp%    
md %temp%    
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\History"\*.*    
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\History"    
md "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\History"    
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files"\*.*    
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files"    
md "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files"    
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp"\*.*    
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp"    
md "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp"    
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Recent"\*.*    
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Recent"    
md "%USERPROFILE%\Recent"    
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Cookies"\*.*    
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Cookies"    
md "%USERPROFILE%\Cookies"
```

Comment: Thank me after... Enjoy!! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
del /s /f /q c:\windows\temp\*.*
rd /s /q c:\windows\temp
md c:\windows\temp
del /s /f /q C:\WINDOWS\Prefetch
del /s /f /q %temp%\*.*
rd /s /q %temp%
md %temp%
deltree /y c:\windows\tempor~1
deltree /y c:\windows\temp
deltree /y c:\windows\tmp
deltree /y c:\windows\ff*.tmp
deltree /y c:\windows\history
deltree /y c:\windows\cookies
deltree /y c:\windows\recent
deltree /y c:\windows\spool\printers
del c:\WIN386.SWP
cls
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
del /f /q C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\temp
```

And it will work.

**Note:** It will delete the whole folder however, Windows will remake it as it needs.