# Using Batch script to clear temp folder in selenium tests

Tags: java, batch-file, selenium

Running a lot of selenium tests causes the temp folder to be filled up with lot 'anonymous-web-driver' profiles in the case of firefox and 'scoped-dirs' in the case of chrome.

To deal with this I came up with the following batch script code

```
@echo off
cd %temp%
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
```

I have the following issues with it

1) It does the job successfully but when the batch script is run on a network drive, it deletes all the files in the current folder since `cd %temp%` does not navigate to the temp as there is no temp folder.

Is there anyway to ensure that lines 3 and 4 are executed only when the current directory is temp. Since the script is stored on a network drive I want to ensure that even if it is run by accident it does cause any unintentional deletion.

2) Since some of the folders cannot be deleted in the temp , the cmd window hangs there saying that these folders could not be deleted.I am fine with the files that cannot be deleted but I want to close the cmd window since I have hundreds of tests to run and each test opening up a cmd window is pretty ugly.

I tried the following `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im cmd.exe");` and it works fine except for the following fact that it kills all cmd processes there are other cmd processes that does some work.Are there ways by which I can close only the cmd window opened by the runtime exec call?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716803

Comment: @rohankamat: That is exactly the place from where I obtained by batch script from the first place.But my question is a little different here.

Comment: @DavidCandy : Can you give me an example.I tried if exist(path to the folder) and then the code but it does the same thing.

Comment: @DavidCandy : Can you post it as an answer with the complete code along with code tag,so that I can better understand.

Comment: I have tried all folder exist possibilities.Somehow the if condition gets run and it deletes content in the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setlocal enableextensions

    pushd "%temp%"
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        rmdir . /s /q >nul 2>nul
        popd
    )
```

And since current directory can't be deleted, it will delete all files and directories not locked.

Comment: Works well..what is the concept behind this? Just want to know

Comment: For the second part I could not find a solution..overcame it by using thread signalling and closed all cmd processes after work is completed.

Comment: Pushd "stores" the current directory in memory and changes to the drive/directory that is indicated, generating an errorlevel if this can't be done. If no errorlevel, try to remove current directory recursively. It starts deleting anything (files, folders) below. Once if finishes, tries to delete current dir, but since we are using it it can´t be deleted. Then `popd` retrieves the stored directory from memory to return to original directory.

Comment: For the second part: rmdir does not wait for file/folder deletion nor blocks (only while working) cmd window. If the window keeps open the problem is in other place. How do you start the batch file ?

Comment: It gets called automatically by a method.Since I had access to the other cmd processes,I leveraged threading and synchronized accordingly.

Comment: I've rereading the original question, and my question is the same, how is the batch file called? by a method you says, but, What code executes de batch? the exact function call, parameters passed, ... Anyway, try to add `exit` at the end of your batch file to "ensure?" window gets closed.

Comment: My original batch script was the one...I was calling it from java using Runtime.exec as cmd /c start "batch file name".When the files could not be deleted the cmd window was open saying the message.But now after adding exit it works fine.Thanks so much and sorry for not telling it in the first place, I was not paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if not "%temp%"=="%CD%" goto :eof
```

Whenever the batch file hits this line it tests if the current directory is equal to the temp directory and if not exits the batch file.